# How to get coordinates and put marker by city name in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, google-maps

Is it possible to get coordinates and put marker on city just by its name? I am trying to get coordinates of my `search` value (it is city). I am using React Native Maps and there is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Alert, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import {SearchBar, Button} from 'react-native-elements';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay';

export default function LinksScreen() {
  const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(false);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const handleChange = event => {
    setSearch(event);
  }
  const [latitudePress, setLatitude] = useState('46.54306');
  const [longitudePress,setLongitude] = useState('14.96917');
  function addMarkerAndRequest(e){
    console.log(e.nativeEvent);
    setLatitude(e.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude); 
    setLongitude(e.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude);
    const coords = {
      latitude: e.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude,
      longitude: e.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude
    };
    Alert.alert(
      'Sprememba mesta',
      'Stanje v komori se bo spremenilo. Ali ste prepričani?',
      [
        {
          text: 'NE',
          style: 'cancel',
        },
        {
          text: 'OK', 
          onPress: () => {
            fetch(`http://192.168.88.253:5000/insert/${coords.longitude}/${coords.latitude}`);
          }
        },
      ],
      {cancelable: false},
    )
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Spinner
          visible={spinner}
          textStyle={styles.spinnerTextStyle}
      />
      <SearchBar
        containerStyle={{borderColor:'#eee', borderWidth:1}}
        placeholder="Vnesi mesto.."
        onChangeText={(e) => {setSearch(e)}}
        value={search}
        platform='android'
      />
      <MapView
        style={{width:'100%', height:'80%'}}
        initialRegion={{
        latitude: Number(latitudePress),
        longitude: Number(longitudePress),
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
        onPress={ (event) => addMarkerAndRequest(event) }
      >
        <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={{latitude: Number(latitudePress),
            longitude: Number(longitudePress)}}
            title={`ZŠ: ${latitudePress}, ZD: ${longitudePress}`}
         />
      </MapView>
      <Button 
        onPress={()=>Alert.alert(
          'Sprememba mesta',
          'Stanje v komori se bo spremenilo. Ali ste prepričani?',
          [
            {
              text: 'NE',
              style: 'cancel',
            },
            {
              text: 'OK', 
              onPress: () => {
                fetch(`http://192.168.88.253:5000/insertcity/${search}`);
                setSearch('');
              }
            },
          ],
          {cancelable: false},
        )}
        title='POTRDI'
      ></Button>
    </View>
  );
}

LinksScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Zemljevid',
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent:'space-between'
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a google places search as described here - https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

You will need to set up a google API key to get it to work (the docs describe how you can do this).

Once you've got the correct response from the places search (the response may return multiple results, but you are looking for the one which has `types` containing the value `locality` - it's a locality/city type place), you can use the response `geometry.location` (check response here - https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#find-place-responses) to get the coordinates and place the marker on your map